# Extracting text from a txt

Tags: unix, grep, sid

My problem is to extract text from lines in /etc/passwd matching a specific pattern

Only text before the ":*" needs to be selected each line

I want the output seperated by commas.

Here's an example:

dog:*dsfgfdh

cat:*bsdfsdf

To:

dog, cat

I have tried something like this which obviously doesnt work

cat /etc/passwd | grep 'a patern'

Anyone with more understanding of grep wanting to help?

Comment: @tripleee it is not a dup.. of the given question.

Answer (score 0):

### Quick & Dirty:

```
awk -F':' -v ORS=", " '$0=$1' /etc/passwd
```

It is "dirty" because the result leaves a comma `,` at the end. Also there is no newline at the end.

### A better version:

```
awk -F':' '{printf "%s%s", NR==1?"":", ", $1}END{print ""}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: That is almost exactly what I want, it only still has the comments in the output: ##, # User Database,

Comment: @GaleHeusen then the answer gave you a good start, just filter out those comment lines you will get what you want. It is an easy step for you I think.